# apache pig JOIN not behaving as expected

Tags: inner-join, apache-pig

I am new to apache pig. I created 2 files with tab separated fields; employees.txt and employees2.txt [there are no line spacings in the files, this is to satisify this editor.]

employees.txt contains:

```
joe     21      94085   50000.0
Tom     21      94085   50000.0
John    21      94085   50000.0
```

employees2.txt contains:

```
joe     4085559898
joe     4085559899
tom     4085559897
tom     4085559896
john    4085559896
```

I then try a simple Join:

```
e1 = LOAD 'employees.txt' AS (name, age, zip, salary);
e2 = LOAD 'employees2.txt' AS (name, phone);
e3 = JOIN e1 BY name, e2 BY name;
DUMP e3;
```

Results:

```
(joe,21,94085,50000.0,joe,4085559899)
(joe,21,94085,50000.0,joe,4085559898)
```

I expected:

```
(joe,21,94085,50000.0,joe,4085559899)
(joe,21,94085,50000.0,joe,4085559898)
(Tom,21,94085,50000.0,Tom,4085559897)
(Tom,21,94085,50000.0,Tom,4085559896)
(joe,21,94085,50000.0,Tom,4085559896)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like nearly all computer languages, Pig is case sensitive.  Thus "Joe" != "joe", and "Tom" != "tom".

You should change the names in the `employees.txt` file to be lower case.  Then you should get the expected results.

You can use the built-in Pig String function [LOWER](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#lower) to accomplish the task of converting the name field to all lowercase.

Something along the lines of:

```
e1 = LOAD 'employees.txt' AS (name, age, zip, salary);
e2 = LOAD 'employees2.txt' AS (name, phone);
e1_lower = FOREACH e1 GENERATE LOWER(name),age,zip,salary;
e3 = JOIN e1_lower BY name, e2 BY name;
DUMP e3;
```